# How to successfully free() a pointer after malloc()

Tags: c, gcc

So pretty much, I am just learning how to allocate memory and work with memory in C. I am using gcc to compile and nano as my editor, here is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   static int *ip, i; 
   main (){
       ip=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
           for(i=0;i<10;++i){
               scanf("%d",ip++);
           }
       free(ip);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
```

When I call the compiler I compile with: 
cd Desktop/C/learn; gcc -W -Werror malloc.c -o run; ./run

The program successfully compiles but after the for statement is finished and free (ip) pointer is called the compiler returns this:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./run: free(): invalid pointer: 0x088ec030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb75e9ee2]
./run[0x80484ce]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb758d4d3]
./run[0x80483d1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23330986   /home/phox/Desktop/run
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:06 23330986   /home/phox/Desktop/run
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:06 23330986   /home/phox/Desktop/run
088ec000-0890d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b753f000-b755b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 14418881   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b755b000-b755c000 r--p 0001b000 08:06 14418881   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b755c000-b755d000 rw-p 0001c000 08:06 14418881   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7573000-b7574000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7574000-b7717000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 14418860   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7717000-b7719000 r--p 001a3000 08:06 14418860   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7719000-b771a000 rw-p 001a5000 08:06 14418860   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b771a000-b771d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7731000-b7735000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7735000-b7736000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7736000-b7756000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 14418840   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7756000-b7757000 r--p 0001f000 08:06 14418840   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7757000-b7758000 rw-p 00020000 08:06 14418840   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bff5b000-bff7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

I am wondering why this is happening and how can I get around this. Is my method not friendly to memory? What is going on here?

How can I re-write the code to make it work?

I am not learning from any book or tutorial or anything. The way I learn a language is read the source code of the compiler or IDE, or the way the language is written -- and go from there. So I don't really have any reference to turn to. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank a lot!
~ Phox

Comment: You need to free the *original* pointer.  You have incremented the pointer 10 times.

Comment: instead of `ip++` say `ip + i`.

Comment: You might like to know that your style of writing C is from about 1970. It would look rather different in modern C.

Comment: Is the information about you editor being `nano` is relevant for your question?

Comment: "questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"...

Comment: @H2C I don't think that's the spirit of that reason - you missed the bit before that "questions asking for code". It clearly isn't a send teh codez question and it even has an SSCCE.

Comment: @Flexo That's precisely why I've edited out the "asking for code" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your pointer ip is not the same as it was in the first place of the malloc. You can fix it by making temporary pointer. example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int *ip, i, *tmp_ip; 
int main (){
   tmp_ip=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
   ip = tmp_ip; // making ip to point the same place as tmp_ip.
   for(i=0;i<10;++i){
     scanf("%d",ip++);
   }
   free(tmp_ip);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to save your *original* pointer in order to free it:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

   void main (){
       int *ip, i; 
       ip=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
       if (ip == NULL) {
         perror ("Memory allocation error");
         return;
       }
       current_p = ip;
       for(i=0;i<10;++i){
           // increment another pointer; don't modify original pointer
           scanf("%d",current_p++);
       }
       free(ip);
   }
```

Or, equivalently:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

   void main (){
       int *ip, *current_p, i; 
       ip=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
       if (ip == NULL) {
         perror ("Memory allocation error");
         return;
       }
       for(i=0;i<10;++i){
           // index; don't modify original pointer
           scanf("%d",ip[i]);
       }
       free(ip);
   }
```

Comment: People, even 30k users don't give a fook about the return type of main?

Comment: Is `null` a C99 (or later) addition to C? Because for C90, I only know `NULL` (or the possibility to use `0` or `(void*)0` directly). And even in C++11 where a built-in constant exists, it's `nullptr`, not `null`.

Comment: @celtschk - simple typo: sorry